# I Try to add Next and Previous Button in my Django Project

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models, django-templates

This is my Url "href="course?lecture={{video.serial_number}}"

this should go like this example:

www.demo. com/course?lecture=1

www.demo. com/course?lecture=2

www.demo. com/course?lecture=3

www.demo. com/course?lecture=4 ( last video )

I Used Below method (IMAGE) it works with previous button but next button not working in last video lecture, like if i have 4 videos (?lecture=4 ) but it continuous to 5th video ( ?lecture=5 ) when i click next button at the end.

[image: I used this code]

Comment: Please include code, not images of code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)